# What is the difference between assert.deepStrictEqual and assert.deepEqual?

Tags: node.js

```js
const assert = require('node:assert')

...

it('should clone', () => {
  const input = { foo: 'bar' }
  const clone = structuredClone(input)
  assert.deepEqual(input, clone)
  assert.deepStrictEqual(input, clone)
})
```

`assert.deepEqual` passes without errors.

On `assert.deepStrictEqual` an error saying:

```
operator: 'deepStrictEqual'
message: 'Values have same structure but are not reference-equal:\n\n{\n  foo: 'bar'\n}\n'
name: 'AssertionError'
```

What does that error message mean?

What are the differences between these functions?

I am using node.js 18.8.0, jest 29.0.3.

Comment: They're all defined in here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8f9d1ab5ec3d3fd2ee4c95f1699c3c10b08108b4/lib/assert.js

Comment: The main impl is `innerDeepEqual` defined here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8f9d1ab5ec3d3fd2ee4c95f1699c3c10b08108b4/lib/internal/util/comparisons.js#L134 - look for where it branches based on whether `strict` is `true` or `false`.

Answer (score -1):

`deepEqual` completes a deep equality comparison, using `==` to compare values that can not contain other values. `deepStrictEqual`, on the other hand, uses `===`. A small difference is that using the strict variant `+0 != -0`.

It appears that the functions are behaving as expected, as calling the following code does not error:

```js
const assert = require('node:assert');

const a = { foo: 'bar' };
const b = { foo: 'bar' };
assert.deepEqual(a, b);
assert.deepStrictEqual(a, b);
```

Instead the difference is probably caused by the implementation of the `structuredClone` function.

The error message is mostly nonsensical and is caused by you giving assert two objects that it knows are different but can't tell why.

Comment: From documentation: "Primitive values are compared using Object.is()." https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertdeepstrictequalactual-expected-message

Why does it fail on my test?